# webrat_steps.rb missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, webrat, railscasts

I'm trying to work through http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber which basically teaches how to use Cucumber within Rails applications.

I installed all missing gems and running `rails g cucumber:install` runs though without issues but misses to create the `features/step_definitions/webrat_steps.rb`.

The setup I'm using is Ruby 1.9.3 (through RVM) and Rails 3.1.3 on Ubuntu. Running `bundle` also contains webrat, rspec, rspec-rails and cucumber (as expected)

So where can I get this file? Why would it now show up?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This file was removed in latest releases of the Cucumber. If you want it back install older version of the gem.

Comment: check http://rubyshow.com/episodes/185?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+rubyshow+%28The+Ruby+Show%29 or http://ruby5.envylabs.com/episodes/216-episode-212-october-7-2011?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Ruby5+%28Ruby5%29 or http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off

Comment: specifically: gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.0.6'